# How to avoid spam filter when sending email as someone else

Tags: php, email, phpmailer, spam

I have a website on which visitors can use a "send to a friend" button. They enter their informations as well as the friend's info.

When I send the email, I want it to be sent with the visitor email / name, but I'm afraid that spam filters will see that this is not sent from the correct domain and mark it as spam.

I'm using the phpMailer library.

Let me know if you need more info!

Comment: Look at this post on Jeff Atwood's blog: http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2010/04/so-youd-like-to-send-some-email-through-code.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

mail systems don't have any way of distinguishing you, who has all good intentions, from others who do not. many applications have Gmail (or other system) credentials specifically for sending messages from their applications, so that they don't have to try and pretend to be a different user. you can add the sender's name in the *from* field, but if you don't try and pretend to be a different sender, you won't raise any red flags.